# PHP create_function with <?PHP ?> tags inside

Tags: php

I´m building a MVC style parser, and I NEEDto be able to process my custom tags (used with the `{}` separator, like `{echo $myVar}`) together with standard PHP code `<?php doSomething ?>` in the same file...

So, after running my parser (that deals with the `{}` scope), I get the following result:

```
if (is_Array($data) && sizeof($data)) extract($data); 
$text = array();$text[] = "
<div class=\"row\">

            <strong>Name: </strong>";$text[] =  $name;$text[] = "<br /> 
            <strong>Description:</strong>";$text[] =  $description;$text[] = "
            <br /> 

            <strong>Status: </strong>
            <?php if ($status == false) : ?>
                <span class=\"label label-danger\">FAILURE</span>
            <?php else : ?>
                <span class=\"label label-success\">OK</span>
            <?php endif; ?> 
            <br />
    </div>
";return implode($text);
```

All fine. From that piece of code I create a function using:

```
function = create_function("\$data", $code);
```

`$code` is the resultset from above.
`$data` is an array containg variables and values like:

```
`$name` => jonas
`$description` => This is test.
`$status`=> false
```

Finally I run:

```
$ret = $function($data);
echo $ret;
```

At that point, I get a problem. All references to variables are removed, but the  tags are not processed, resulting in a kind of wierd code like:

```
<div class="row">

            <strong>Name: </strong>jonas"<br /> 
            <strong>Description:</strong>This is test.<br /> 

            <strong>Status: </strong>
            <?php if ( == false) : ?>  <<<<<========== WRONG CODE
                <span class=\"label label-danger\">FAILURE</span>
            <?php else : ?>
                <span class=\"label label-success\">OK</span>
            <?php endif; ?> 
            <br />
    </div>
```

So, the variables are substituted, except for the  code that is neither solved nor have the variables correctly replaced.

I wish I can get a solution for that problem... Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably going about this in an inefficient manner...but to *purely* fix the problem you are having with your current code, just take the conditionals out of the quotations.

```
if (is_Array($data) && sizeof($data)) extract($data); 
$text = array();$text[] = "
<div class=\"row\">

            <strong>Name: </strong>";$text[] =  $name;$text[] = "<br /> 
            <strong>Description:</strong>";$text[] =  $description;$text[] = "
            <br /> 

            <strong>Status: </strong>";
            if ($status == false) :
                $text[] = "<span class=\"label label-danger\">FAILURE</span>";
            else :
                $text[] = "<span class=\"label label-success\">OK</span>";
            endif;
            $text[] = "<br />
    </div>
";return implode($text);
```

Comment: Hmmm.... What would be the efficient manner ? Removing the `<?php ?` tags will lead me to incorrect PHP written code... I just want to be able to add my `{}`tags inside a standard PHP code without changing it...

Comment: @Mendez, a more efficient way would be having a template file that is rendered in PHP with your variables passed into it...this would avoid all of the HTML templates in PHP strings (and backslashing double quotes, etc). *My code does work,* ***try it.*** If you are getting in valid error, double check it and then update your question with the new error.

Comment: I have fixed the problem on the parser... Thanks for help.

Answer (score -1):

You must ecape the variable declaration, as it will be parsed by php. Then process your php code stored in a string with eval().